# Purchased DDR3 RAM but it is super small for my tower computer

Tags: memory, motherboard, ramdisk

I recently bought a small tower computer ([Dell OptiPlex, Intel Core 2 Duo 2.9GHz E7500 Processor, 4GB Memory, 160GB Hard Drive, DVD, Windows 10 Home, WiFi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AWOAUJY)) that said it takes DDR3 RAM, so I bought this RAM off of Amazon.com ([Samsung 2GB PC-8500 DDR3 1066MHz SO-DIMM 204 Pin 2.0GB Memory Upgrade Modules M471B5673FH0-CF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BJ37JO)).

However, when it arrived it was a third the size of the ram it should be replacing, and does not fit. Does the computer not take DDR3 Ram? Are there multiple sizes of RAM? Is the product listing on Amazon wrong?

Pictures for reference below.

[image: Dell OptiPlex]

[image: Samsung 2GB PC-8500 DDR3 1066MHz]

Comment: I advise you to study up on the different types of DDR3 RAM before purchasing again. There are only a few distinctions you need to be aware of, but they are important distinctions and they are all well documented.

Comment: Sites such as Crucial and Kensington will walk you through all the RAM options for your particular computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You bought [SO-DIMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM) instead of [regular RAM modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM). The ones you got are meant to used in smaller form factor computers (e.g. laptops).

Comment: OP should see mobo docs and select one of the supported RAM modules.

Answer (score 6):

You bought an [SO-DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM) module rather than a [DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM).

SO-DIMM modules are used in laptops where space is at more of a premium than desktop machines. The "SO" stands for "Small Outline"

Generally if you are in doubt of what type of modules you need then you should check your motherboard manual, or Crucial have a [memory checker](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/systemscanner) that can scan your system and suggest memory modules that should work.

Answer (score -2):

You bought SODIMM instead of UDIMM. There are only 2 sizes, and as this was posted, there are a total of 5 slot types (10 if you include SODIMM). But no need to buy a new one; just use an adapter [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QCFCCL3). Also, GB is just the size, which means there's no limit. Okay, technically there is, but all motherboards prevent going over the limit.

Comment: Yes there's limits, also there's punctuation that your post needs. Adapters should not be used it at all possible because they introduce complexity and latency and more parts to interfere and fail. Especially if the RAM is new, returning it and getting the correct type is the correct action. Finally, besides your comment about there being an adapter, the rest of the useful information in this post is already contained in the other answers. While answering old questions is OK, it is best to do so only if you have substantial new and helpful information the existing answers do not contain.